# Angular CdkDragDrop inside a table cell, and drag across rows

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular7

I'm trying to add a table in Angular 7, where one of the columns includes a list, and I would like to allow the user to drag and drop any of these list items across different rows.

I have been trying to use CdkDragDrop, and place it inside a table, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Please find code below:

```
    <table
    mat-table
    [dataSource]="general"
    style="width:100%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 50px"
    *ngIf="general.data.length !== 0">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Camera_Physical_Index">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Camera Physical Index</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        {{ element.Camera_Physical_Index }}
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Analytical_Function">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Analytical Function</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <div
          cdkDropList
          [cdkDropListData]="general.data"
          (cdkDropListDropped)="dropGroup($event)"
        >
          <div
            cdkDropListGroup
            class="example-container"
            cdkDrag
            [cdkDragData]="element"
          >
            <div
              cdkDropList
              class="example-list"
              id="{{ element.Camera_Physical_Index }}"
              [cdkDropListData]="element.Analytical_Function"
              (cdkDropListDropped)="dropItem($event)"
              [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="getConnectedList()"
            >
              <div
                class="example-box"
                *ngFor="let item of element.Analytical_Function"
                cdkDrag
                [cdkDragData]="item"
              >
                {{ item }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="generalColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: generalColumns"></tr>
  </table>
```

The desired outcome is as follows:

[Desired UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABS0f.png)

Answer (score 2):

To make the lists connected, you should put **cdkDropListGroup** in ng-container of the column so it will includes all lists (list of each row) of this column.

Please find the bellow stackblitz where I tried to make an example as yours:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzbupf

In general:
If you have multiple lists and you want to drag from one to another:

1. you should connect all these lists by the directive **cdkDropListGroup** in the global so it will group and connect them automatically.
2. add **cdkDropList** around each draggable item
3. add **cdkDrag** to items so it make them draggable
4. add **cdkDropListDropped** event to listen to it in order to update the data model once the user finishes dragging.

[angular material](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview)